# Create boolean attribute in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design

I have to create a table in Oracle and one column I have to make it of Boolean type. Can you please tell me how can I do that? I have searched on the internet but I couldn't find a clear answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no BOOLEAN datatype in SQL.  But we can represent it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tt
  (test NUMBER(1) NOT NULL CHECK  (test in (0,1)))
```

Comment: Ah, nice. How about the overhead of that check?

Comment: but can I somehow create a TYPE named boolean and after that add the field boolean in my table?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes, but do we want better performance and errors, or little bit less performance and errors ?

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Nobody wants errors, but I don't see any. Do you? See my other comment: Simply treat everything that is not 0 as true. This has a long history in computing.

Comment: this is not for a real daily use implementation. I have a school project and my teacher gave my this schema, with a boolean attribute.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I understand this point of view... I still think that making things easier (myValue = 1 is as consistent as myValue <> 0) is a good thing for a boolean representation. And you can't force everyone to have c++ logic in mind ;)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - my vote is for data consistency.  If a column should hold only 1 or 0 have a check constraint to enforce.  Because if history teaches us anything it is this: develoeprs will build code assuming that column holds only 1 or 0, code which works wrongly when it contains 3.

Comment: Also, if we're going to cheesepare performance overheads, CHAR(1) takes up less space than NUMBER(1).  Over the lifetime of a record I bet that extra byte costs more than enforcing a check constraint.

Comment: @APC: Good point about the assumption of developers. My question about the performance was actually an honest one as I don't know how "severe" the performance impact is. I surely am no micro-optimizer, I just wanted to know if there is a gotcha in high-volume scenarios. Guess I could have formulated that better :)

Comment: @DanielHilgarth - well you know Knuth said about *that*.

Comment: @APC: Sorry, I don't follow.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth "Premature optimization is the root of all evil." http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth

Comment: @APC: I thought I made clear that I am not such a person. But that doesn't mean that it isn't a good idea to know about performance implications of the techniques you use.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [CREATE TYPE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_8001.htm) for Oracle.

In some databases it is possible to define your own boolean data type (this does *not* work in Oracle, I'm told, but it illustrates the idea):

```
CREATE DOMAIN BOOLEAN
AS NUMBER(1)
NOT NULL
CHECK (value IN (0,1))
```

This can be used as any other type for table columns.

Comment: I get this error: ORA-00901: invalid CREATE command 

EDIT: as I saw on the internet, CREATE DOMAIN is not part of ORACLE SQL

Comment: Look at CREATE TYPE for Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no boolean data type. You have to use `NUMBER(1)`.

Comment: hmmm, seems to be a little bit short, I can put 3 in your field...

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: I know. If you have a better solution, I would be *glad* to hear it. I never found one. But it really isn't a problem. Just treat that field like C++ does: 0 means false, not 0 means true.

Answer (score -4):

Read about Virtual Column in Oracle doc and use numbers as suggested by others: 0-false, 1-true. No BOOLEAN datatype in CREATE table in Oracle.

Comment: What has virtual columns got to do with this?  They're a cool mechanism for holding (or appearing to hold) denomralised data.

Comment: As for virtual columns, I know what they do.  What I fail to see is their relevance *here*, to this question.  If you think they are pertinent you should edit your "answer" to include some sample code.  That would at least be different to the existing answers.  Who knows, I might even upvote you...

Comment: @APC- The question was about creating Boolean attr. in Oracle table. I mentioned that others have answered regarding the Boolean and suggested using virt. column for calculations as this is the feature that van be used in CREATE TABLE as the question states. I hope you got it now. You and others can downvote me all you want - I do not get anything for scores and not looking for recognition. I'm learning and helping and thankful unlike many others...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24048/discussion-between-apc-and-art)